# Finding #NA values after Vlookup between two excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

We have two sheets for Jan and Aug. Both consist of two columns: One for Client name and one for the number of shares they attain. We have to find out client names:

1. Which exist in Jan but not in Aug
2. Which exist in Aug but not in Jan
3. Which exist in both Jan and Aug

For third one we can simply use Vlookup function but for first and second condition if we use Vlookup then it will return #NA and we want these #NA values.

Please suggest how we can achieve 1 & 2 condition.

Comment: Why not just copy january's list with "jan" next to it, and august's list with "aug" next to it and then highlight duplicates? Those highlighted will be shared and then filter on the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have your lookups working, inserting them into logic of the following form should work:

```
1. IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(<lookup_in_jan>)),ISNA(<lookup_in_aug)),<client_name>, "")
2. IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(<lookup_in_aug>)),ISNA(<lookup_in_jan)),<client_name>, "")
3. IF(AND(NOT(ISNA(<lookup_in_aug>)),NOT(ISNA(<lookup_in_jan))),<client_name>, "")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

But there is an issue.

I am unable to find ISNA function in my excel.

For using this formula, I have to use which version of office?

Comment: This function should be available in any version from 2000 onwards according to http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isna.php. I tested in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you already have 1 & 2, similar to how you achieved 3; if you VLOOKUP an Aug client name in the Jan sheet, and it shows up NA, that implies it does not exist in Jan, so you have 2, and vice versa.

If you want the explicit name (repeated in that case), you could do:

```
IF(ISNA(<your_vlookup_cell_ref>),<your_name_cell_ref>,"")
```